# What is the difference between differential yield and selectivity?

Tags: reaction-control, chemical-engineering

I have a hard time understanding the difference between the differential yield and overall selectivity of a reaction.

Levenspiel, Chemical Reaction Engineering writes:

> For convenience in evaluating
> product distribution we introduce two terms, p and a. First, consider the decomposition of reactant A, and let cp be the fraction of A disappearing at any instant
> which is transformed into desired product R. We call this the instantaneous
> fractional yield of R. For any particular set of reactions and rate equations cp is a function of CA, and since CA in general varies through the reactor, p will also change with
> position in the reactor:
> $ \varphi = \frac{-dC_A}{dC_S}$

and for selectivity:

> The Selectivity. Another term, the selectivity, is often used in place of fractional
> yield. It is usually defined as follows:
> $$\text{selectivity} = \frac{\text{moles of desired product formed}}{\text{moles of undesired material formed}}$$

So how do they differ? How can I imagine both?

Aside from that, they also provide some nice plots:
[image: Levenspiel, Chemical Reaction Engineering]

One question I have:
How can I imagine the selectivity for a MFR (gray area) crossing the selectivity curve? The formula for the integral yield for a PFR/MFR make sense, but how do I imagine that in a practical sense?

Also: What does the curve describe?

Answer (score 1):

First, these two concepts as you may already know are useful for describing various chemical reactions taking place or **multiple reactions**. Why Levenspiel wants you to know these concepts? Because you are interested, typically, in one product, not all of them.

As an example, consider the following reaction scheme, where you **are interested in B**; and we assume power rate laws for both of them:

$$ A \rightarrow B \hspace{1 cm} r_1 = r_{1,B} = - r_{1,A} = k_1C_A^2 $$

$$ 2A \rightarrow C \hspace{1 cm} r_2 = r_{2,C} = -r_{2, A} = 2k_2C_A^3 $$

The fractional yield of $A$ and selectivity are

$$ \phi_{B/A} = \dfrac{r_{1,B}}{-(r_{1,A} + r_{2,A})} = \dfrac{k_1C_A^2}{k_1C_A^2 + 2k_2C_A^3} $$

$$ S_{B} = \dfrac{n_B}{n_C} $$

So now we can answer your first question:

1. The fractional yield gives you, as a function of the concentration of species $A$, the rate of formation of the species **you want** with respect to the rate of consumption (with a negative sign) of the reactant $A$. As an engineer, what do you want to do? **Maximize this quantity once we give you a type of flow within a reactor**. This does not mean maximizing $ B $, but will give you the best exchange between the reactant $ A $ and your valuable product $ B $.
2. The selectivity gives you, as a function of time or position, the amount in moles formed of the species **you want** with respect to the amount of moles of the species you **do not want**. As an engineer, what will they ask you? **Minimize this quantity once we give you a type of flow within a reactor**. As before, this does not mean that you will generate a lot of $ B $, rather, it will give you the best exchange in terms of generating $ B $ and not generating $ C $.

Levenspiel states that this definition is not useful, because **it may be hard to quantify in moles all of the species that you don't want** (imagine 1 valuable product and 19 not valuable products). However, a more useful mathematical definition would be the one I give you below, analogous to the yield

$$ S_{B/C} = \dfrac{r_{1,B}}{r_{2,C}} = \dfrac{k_1C_A^2}{2k_2C_A^3} $$

Lets go now to the second part. The curves you are seeing there are indeed the fractional yield vs the concentration of $A$, i.e., $\phi_{R/A}(C_A)$ vs $C_A$. **They only depend on the kinetic rate laws governing the reaction scheme**. However, in this case, thay are so simple that they only depend on the concentration of only one reactant. Depending on the mathematical form, they may have a maximum, or not, or have rare behaviours (imagine how the rate law may dramatically change with a catalyst, etc.). In addition, they also give you the concentration of $R$, i.e., the species you want. For a MFR, it is a rectangle of base $ C_{A0} - C_A $ and height $\phi_{R/A}(C_A)$. For a PFR, it is the area under the curve bounded between $ C_{A0} $ and $ C_A $, as you said.

The MFR **can't operate passing the curve**, because its type of flow is such that its operating point is the exit; such that the whole reactor "exists" as a unique point in that curve.